# resize() fires on page load (jQuery, Firefox)

Tags: jquery

The alert() in code below fires on page load but it shouldn't. Why does it?

```
jQuery(window).bind("load", function() {
    jQuery(window).resize(function() { 
        alert('hi');
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you mean that you see the `alert()` on page load?

Comment: I tested. It doesn't alert for me.

Comment: `jQuery(window).resize()` there might be other call in the script somewhere else.

Comment: Yes I see the alert() on page load. And also yes there is another jQuery(window).resize() elsewhere indeed, but it does something else not an alert(). Why would this other call trigger my alert() ?

Answer (score -1):

You can simple use

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery(window).resize(function() { 
        alert('hi');
    });

});
```

it is work for me well

Comment: I am using bind("load"...) for a reason. I can't use jQuery(document).ready(function(){}) in this particular case.